# spring mvc 3 and google datatable

Tags: java, spring-mvc, datatable, datasource, google-visualization

I am new to google.visualization.datasource and I was wondering if there is a simple example for creating the datatable with a helper class and return it back to the client but, without using query and DataSourceServlet?? because I am already implementing my http request via spring mvc controller.

I was trying to implement the following example: https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/dev/dsl_get_started

Here is my code:

```
    @Controller
public class DBcontroller {
private SimpleDateFormat formater = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");


@SuppressWarnings({ "rawtypes", "unchecked" })
@RequestMapping(value = "/getHistoricalData", method = {RequestMethod.POST,RequestMethod.GET})
public @ResponseBody DataTable setLampsRequest(@RequestParam String Lampid
        , @RequestParam String StartDate, @RequestParam String EndDate) throws ParseException{

    //converting time values to long
    Long start = formater.parse(StartDate).getTime();
    Long end = formater.parse(EndDate).getTime();

     // Create a data table,
    DataTable data = new DataTable();
    ArrayList cd = new ArrayList();
    cd.add(new ColumnDescription("name", ValueType.TEXT, "Animal name"));
    cd.add(new ColumnDescription("link", ValueType.TEXT, "Link to wikipedia"));
    cd.add(new ColumnDescription("population", ValueType.NUMBER, "Population size"));
    cd.add(new ColumnDescription("vegeterian", ValueType.BOOLEAN, "Vegetarian?"));

    data.addColumns(cd);

    // Fill the data table.
    try {
      data.addRowFromValues("Aye-aye", "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aye-aye", 100, true);
      data.addRowFromValues("Sloth", "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sloth", 300, true);
      data.addRowFromValues("Leopard", "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leopard", 50, false);
      data.addRowFromValues("Tiger", "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tiger", 80, false);
    } catch (TypeMismatchException e) {
      System.out.println("Invalid type!");
    }


    return data;
 }  

 }
```

Thank you in advance any help appreciated.

Comment: What issue are you running in to? What have you tried? There is nothing wrong with creating a dataTable separately, so long as the final format is readable as a JS object by Google Visualization. So if it is a proper object, using it as the datasource should cause no problems with creating the chart. Where is your problem exactly?

Comment: @jmac I tried to convert to JSON object through google.gson
When I receive it in the browser and make a google.Visualization.Datatable from it and try to draw it I get this error in the console:

`Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'getNumberOfColumns')`

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `JsonRenderer` to write the DataTable as JSON:

```java
@RequestMapping(value = "/getHistoricalData", method = {RequestMethod.POST,RequestMethod.GET})
public @ResponseBody void setLampsRequest(
            @RequestParam String Lampid, 
            @RequestParam String StartDate, 
            @RequestParam String EndDate, 
            Writer output, 
            HttpServletRequest request) {

    //converting time values to long
    Long start = formater.parse(StartDate).getTime();
    Long end = formater.parse(EndDate).getTime();

    // Create a data table,
    DataTable data = new DataTable();
    ArrayList cd = new ArrayList();
    cd.add(new ColumnDescription("name", ValueType.TEXT, "Animal name"));
    cd.add(new ColumnDescription("link", ValueType.TEXT, "Link to wikipedia"));
    cd.add(new ColumnDescription("population", ValueType.NUMBER, "Population size"));
    cd.add(new ColumnDescription("vegeterian", ValueType.BOOLEAN, "Vegetarian?"));

    data.addColumns(cd);

    // Fill the data table.
    try {
      data.addRowFromValues("Aye-aye", "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aye-aye", 100, true);
      data.addRowFromValues("Sloth", "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sloth", 300, true);
      data.addRowFromValues("Leopard", "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leopard", 50, false);
      data.addRowFromValues("Tiger", "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tiger", 80, false);
    } catch (TypeMismatchException e) {
      System.out.println("Invalid type!");
    }
    PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(output);
    writer.println(JsonRenderer.renderDataTable(data, true, false, false));
    writer.close();
}
```